# SET IDENTITY_INSERT using a linked server on dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server

I need to insert a record on two tables on different servers.

The table has the same structure on both places and it has an identity column so I need to run a dynamic sql, generate the same id and insert it on both servers.

For example: I'm on `[SERVER_A]` trying to insert the record into `[SERVER_A].MyDB.dbo.Mytable` and `[SERVER_B].MyDB.dbo.Mytable`. I get the last id inserted from both tables and I push the new record using the last id + 1.

So far so good, now I need to use dynamic SQL to set the `identity_insert` using:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [SERVER_B].MyDB.dbo.Mytable ON
```

The only way is to run it on this way:

```
@Qry = 'SET IDENTITY_INSERT MyDB.dbo.Mytable ON'
EXEC [SERVER_B].MyDb.dbo.sp_executesql ' + @Qry
```

The problem is that `[SERVER_B]` will be a variable so I need to put the previous sentence something like this:

```
EXEC '[SERVER_B]' + '.MyDb.dbo.sp_executesql ' + @Qry
```

Is there any way to do achieve this? I'm putting this as example but the idea is to push the insert with an specific id so for that I need the `IDENTITY_INSERT ON`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it's crazy... but I found a solution:

```
DECLARE @Qry nvarchar(MAX)
DECLARE @Server nvarchar(50) = '[SERVER_B]'

SET @Qry = '
    DECLARE @Qry2 nvarchar(max)
    SET @Qry2 = N''
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.MyTable on
    insert dbo.MyTable (id, Name) values (34, ''''AnyName'''')
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.MyTable off''
    EXEC ' + @Server + '.MyDb.dbo.sp_executesql @Qry2'
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @Qry
```